# Optimize a SQL Sum on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, aggregate-functions

I have had to make a bit of a monster query that is used is being used to calculate the number of tools used to manufacture some widgets. As many tools can be used across many widgets and a bunch of stuff is done in the background to associate widgets to tools, involving tables with thousands of rows, so the whole thing is a little slow. The problem I am now having is order to get the count of widgets and tools right, I am having to divide them back down by the amount they are repeated - and to do this I have to do a Sum on the already slow query I am running, which makes things exponentially slower. Is there any more intelligent way to do what I am doing ? I'm developing in SQL express so I don't have access to query analyzers and such that would help a lot.

So here is a simplified version of what I am doing - I won't go into the crazy mad joins just yet as I think the sum is the main offender

So this is the data out of my query - yes it looks messy, but this is what the end application requires (beyond my control alas, otherwise it would be parameterised views). Its just doing a flat sum on the T_QTY column. What we actually have is one set of tool transactions 13 and 6, giving 19 tools in total, but its repeated as they were used in all those widget families. Like wise only 5 wheels were made but its listed twice as two tools were used. So when it does the flat sum it gets a bananas figure.

```
Select [Tool Date], [T_ID], [T_Trns], [T_QTY], [Widget Date], [W_Family], [W_QTY] from my_Widget_view
```

```
[Tool Date] [T_ID] [T_Trns] [T_QTY] [Widget Date] [W_Family] [W_QTY]
 01/01/17     T11     11       13      01/02/17     Wheels       5
 01/01/17     T11     12       6       01/02/17     Wheels       5
 01/01/17     T11     11       13      01/02/17     Keyboards    7
 01/01/17     T11     12       6       01/02/17     Keyboards    7
 01/01/17     T11     11       13      01/02/17     Mice         3
 01/01/17     T11     12       6       01/02/17     Mice         3
                              ---
                            sum = 57 (wrong !)
```

If I wanted to Sum my QTY column correctly I need to know the number of transactions and family's that were used for that tool and divide down to correct - so I have to do a monster sub query like so.

```
Select 

[T_ID], 
(select sum([T_Trns]) from my_Widget_view as A where A.[T_ID] = B.[T_ID] and A.[Tool Date] = b.[Tool Date] ) as Trns_cnt

[T_QTY], 
   [T_QTY] / (select sum([W_Family]) from my_Widget_view as A where A.[T_ID] = B.[T_ID] and A.[Tool Date] = b.[Tool Date] ) /(select sum([T_Trns]) from my_Widget_view as A where A.[T_ID] = B.[T_ID] and A.[Tool Date] = b.[Tool Date] ) as divcnt

[W_Family],
(select sum([W_Family]) from my_Widget_view as A where A.[T_ID] = B.[T_ID] and A.[Tool Date] = b.[Tool Date] ) as Fmly_cnt
[W_QTY] 
from my_Widget_view as B
```

This gives (leaving out some rows from the above for readability

```
[Tool Date]  [T_Trns] [Trns_cnt] [T_QTY] [divcnt] [W_Family] [W_QTY] [Fmly_cnt]
 01/01/17        11          2       13      4.33    Wheels       5     6
 01/01/17        12          2       6       2       Wheels       5     6
 01/01/17        11          2       13      4.33    Keyboards    7     6
 01/01/17        12          2       6       2       Keyboards    7     6
 01/01/17        11          2       13      4.33    Mice         3     6
 01/01/17        12          2       6       2       Mice         3     6
                                            ---
                                         sum = 19 (right !)
```

I hope this all makes sense, I'm not really a full time SQL developer so apologies for any mistakes or glaring errors.

Comment: I think this question would definitely benefit from a clearer presentation of the *input* data (I assume it comes from multiple tables) with irrelevant columns removed. I assume all you're showing us at the moment is the broken output and the desired output..

Comment: Yes sorry, these are the two ouput queries. I didn't want to get into the raw inputs part as it would at least double the size of the question and while its got its own issues I think most of my issues are coming from summing again and again on the same table. The source data is basically 3k rows of tool data, 27k rows of widget data, then a table to associate tools to Family (13k rows), and then another table to associate the family to the widgets (3k rows).

Comment: But the logical place to *fix* this is to avoid the under-constrained joins that are causing your totals to be multiplied by the unrelated entities.

Comment: Ah sorry, thats not clear from the question, but unfortunately I need those unconstrained joins as there are additional columns not in the question that are needed. This data is going to a visualization tool that seems to just support the data in one flat table, and this is the only way to represent both the widgets and tools and all the required data in one big view. I cannot constrain the joins any more sadly

Comment: Step 1: Press CTRL-L to see the query plan and see if it suggests any indexes. These indexes _might_ help - test beforehand and after. What version of SQL Server? later versions give access to windowing functions that may help. Having said that, it's difficult to attack this one. You could for example zero out the T_QTY lines so that they only appear once then the sum would be correct but you would have zero against some W_Family. Is that acceptable? Sounds like a crappy reporting tool anyway. You know Power BI is free right?

Answer (score 0):

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggests, I think your problems might be better fixed by re-implementing my_Widget_View, but if you really can't, you could try using a couple of subqueries to shape the data before you sum it:

```
select  Tool_Date,
        T_ID,
        sum(T_QTY),
        sum(W_QTY)
from    (select distinct
                Tool_Date,
                T_ID,
                T_TRNS,
                T_QTY
        from    my_Widget_View) dt 
        join 
        (select distinct
                Tool_Date,
                T_ID,
                W_QTY
        from    my_Widget_View) df 
        on dt.T_ID = df.T_ID and dt.Tool_Date = df.ToolDate
```